# How to reference sibling id in mongodb without printing that particular sibling

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgN4X.png)
I'm trying to use mongosh to retrieve the details of the other siblings, i.e Child2 and Child3 by referencing the child1 document.
What mongosh condition should I use to get this and not the child1 and father document?

I tried the aggregate method and the find method, I tried to apply the logic of using the parent_id, which is common among the other siblings, but it prints the child1 id as well. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some trial and error and I used the `$ne` function. So according to the image, the answer should be:

```
db.family.find({parent_id: "1", _id:{$ne:2}})
```